# Error. replacement has 12 rows, data has 7

Tags: r

I am trying to make a sum of several variables grouping by 2 factors ("CODE" and "Municipality") and create a new variable, named n_clients, based on a third factor "COD_CONTRACT_ENCRIPTED". I have a dataframe with 28 variables. 24 of them correspond to the hours of the day. I want to perform the sum of each of the hours, grouping by the two factors I am interested in.

I apply the following code:

```
CURVAS_Cliente_suma = CURVAS %>%  
  group_by(CODIGO, Municipio) %>% #agrupar por Municipio
  summarise(H_00 = sum(H_00, na.rm=T),
              H_01 = sum(H_01, na.rm=T),H_02 = sum(H_02, na.rm=T),H_03 = sum(H_03, na.rm=T),H_04 = sum(H_04, na.rm=T),
              H_05 = sum(H_05, na.rm=T),H_06 = sum(H_06, na.rm=T),H_07 = sum(H_07, na.rm=T),H_08 = sum(H_08, na.rm=T),
              H_09 = sum(H_09, na.rm=T),H_10 = sum(H_10, na.rm=T),H_11 = sum(H_11, na.rm=T),H_12 = sum(H_12, na.rm=T),
              H_13 = sum(H_13, na.rm=T),H_14 = sum(H_14, na.rm=T),H_15 = sum(H_15, na.rm=T),H_16 = sum(H_16, na.rm=T),
              H_17 = sum(H_17, na.rm=T),H_18 = sum(H_18, na.rm=T),H_19 = sum(H_19, na.rm=T),H_20 = sum(H_20, na.rm=T),
              H_21 = sum(H_21, na.rm=T),H_22 = sum(H_22, na.rm=T),H_23 = sum(H_23, na.rm=T),
              n_clientes = length(unique(COD_CONTRATO_ENCRIPTADO)))
```

When executing the code I receive the following error:

```
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "call_text", value = c("CURVAS %>% group_by(CODIGO, Municipio) %>% ...",  : 
  replacement has 12 rows, data has 7
```

I have initially tried creating the variable n_clients with NA values, but I still get the same error.

Comment: ^ agree. You might also consider using `summarise(across(H_00:H_23, ~sum(.x, na.rm=TRUE)))` in place of your many summing terms.

Comment: @Phil, `length(unique(.))` should always return length-1.